# Why action in controller return view() can direct to other view with same name?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

My project called nopCommerce, which is open source.

I download it and start to develop.

When I visit index, run into Index() in HomeController.cs.

```
public partial class HomeController : BasePublicController
{
    public virtual IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

return view(), direct to the same view named **\Views\Home\Index.cshtml**

I can understand it.

This project can plug theme, I plug a theme by copying its code to \Themes\Views\

When I visit this index after plugged, It returns view() directly to **\Themes\Views\Home\Index.cshtml**

I can not understand it.

Why the action in controller return view() can direct to other view with same name?

I try to renamed **\Themes\Views\Home\Index.cshtml**

It direct to **\Views\Home\Index.cshtml**

Comment: Do you just copy the view code ? Or also copy the controller code?

Comment: No,I don't copy it. I appreciate your reply

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you got to do certain changes in RouteConfig.cs or using [ActionName("")]

Comment: Thank you,but it is not in RouteConfig.cs or using [ActionName("")].

Comment: I appreciate your reply

Answer (score 0):

I found it,the project will set ViewLocationExpanderContext by theme name